# using awk to count characters and modify file accordingly

Tags: awk, counting

I have a file that looks like this

```
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:2703:2197#0/1
CAGCTTTACTCGTCATTTCCCCCAAGGGTAAAATGCGTCCGTCCATTAAGTTCACAGTCATCGTCT
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:2703:2197#0/1
^`^\eggcghheJ`dffhhhffhe`ecd^a^_ceacecfhf\beZegfhh_fghhgfZbdg]c^a`
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:4434:2244#0/1
CTGCGTTCATCGCGTTGTTGGGAGGAATCTCTACCCCAGGTTCTCGCTGTGAA
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:4434:2244#0/1
eeecgeceeffhhihi_fhhiicdgfghiiihiiihiiihVbcdgfhge`cee
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:6394:2107#0/1
CAGCAGGACTAGGGCCTGCAGACGTACTG
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:6394:2107#0/1
eeeccggeghhiihiihihihhhhcfghf
```

I would like to go to every second line and count the number of characters. If the line contains less than e.g. 66 characters then fill it to 66 with 'A' and print to new file. If it contains 66 characters then just print the line as is.

The output file would look like this;

```
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:2703:2197#0/1
CAGCTTTACTCGTCATTTCCCCCAAGGGTAAAATGCGTCCGTCCATTAAGTTCACAGTCATCGTCT
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:2703:2197#0/1
^`^\eggcghheJ`dffhhhffhe`ecd^a^_ceacecfhf\beZegfhh_fghhgfZbdg]c^a`
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:4434:2244#0/1
CTGCGTTCATCGCGTTGTTGGGAGGAATCTCTACCCCAGGTTCTCGCTGTGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:4434:2244#0/1
eeecgeceeffhhihi_fhhiicdgfghiiihiiihiiihVbcdgfhge`ceeAAAAAAAAAAAAA
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:6394:2107#0/1
CAGCAGGACTAGGGCCTGCAGACGTACTGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:6394:2107#0/1
eeeccggeghhiihiihihihhhhcfghfAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

I have a very basic knowledge of awk so from a learning perspective I would like to use awk to solve the problem.

Comment: You have a typo on the last line of your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be faster than the accepted approach:

```
awk 'NR%2==0 { x = sprintf("%-66s", $0); gsub(/ /,"A",x); $0 = x }1' file
```

Results:

```
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:2703:2197#0/1
CAGCTTTACTCGTCATTTCCCCCAAGGGTAAAATGCGTCCGTCCATTAAGTTCACAGTCATCGTCT
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:2703:2197#0/1
^`^\eggcghheJ`dffhhhffhe`ecd^a^_ceacecfhf\beZegfhh_fghhgfZbdg]c^a`
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:4434:2244#0/1
CTGCGTTCATCGCGTTGTTGGGAGGAATCTCTACCCCAGGTTCTCGCTGTGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:4434:2244#0/1
eeecgeceeffhhihi_fhhiicdgfghiiihiiihiiihVbcdgfhge`ceeAAAAAAAAAAAAA
@FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:6394:2107#0/1
CAGCAGGACTAGGGCCTGCAGACGTACTGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
+FCD17BKACXX:8:1101:6394:2107#0/1
eeeccggeghhiihiihihihhhhcfghfAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: It was 24 minutes faster in processing a file with ~310 million lines.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
awk '!(NR%2) && length<66{for(i=length;i<66;i++)$0=$0 "A"}1' file
```

Comment: nice but you don't need the initial test for "&& length<66" since the loop condition already takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR%2 == 0{
    printf("%s", $0)
    for(i=length($0); i<66; i++)printf("A")
    print "";next }
    {print}'
```

Comment: i didn't test it, however this will lose all odd lines in output. right? fix it if I am right.

Comment: Ah, you are right. From OP's description it wasn't 100% clear if the odd lines should be printed, but from the expected output it was very clear. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would paste another **strange** (maybe) oneliner:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{while(++i<66)t=t"A"}!(NR%2){$0=$0substr(t,length)}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS= '{printf "%s",$0} !(NR%2){for (i=NF+1;i<=66;i++) printf "A"} {print ""}'
```

or if you don't like loops:

```
awk -v FS= '{sfx=(NR%2 ? "" : sprintf("%*s",66-NF,"")); gsub(/ /,"A",sfx); print $0 sfx}'
```